# Call a method that is in my helper on rails 5

Tags: ruby, class, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I have this helper for a session in rails 5 and it's calling to the user table and then session table, that's because I have it related in my database, the code is the following one:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def generate_user_session
    session_build = user.sessions.build
    session_build.generate_access_token
    session_build.save!
  end
end
```

The problem is when I called the method in a controller it appears this error:

> `undefined local variable or method 'user'`

I know this error is due to I'm not referring well to my helper in my controller, the question is...

**How is the correct form I can call a method from a helper in my controller?**

---

***Note:*** Consider that in my helper I'm calling to my table user that is also calling the table sessions.

Comment: Helper methods are intended to be called from *views*, not controllers. If you want this to be a controller method that's also a helper method, use the `helper_method` declaration in your controller.

Comment: I would change the approach to be something that's run from a controller since a session is something that follows a CRUDE concept - A session is something you may want to create, delete (or update). 
See example https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login

Comment: May be move method `generate_user_session` to `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a variable (`user`) that's only available on your controller. You may try to set and use @user as `instance_variable`.

But as tadman write, you shouldn't use helper to controller propose.

If it is for session proposes you could use a `concern` or create a new Class to deal with this.